# i was trying to make a dictionary using tuple as key , But while accessing it gives this error

Tags: python, dictionary

```
gn={('A','S'):140,('A','Z'):75,('A','T'):118,('Z','O'):71,('S','0'):151,('S','R'):80,('S','F'):99,('F','B'):211,('R','P'):97,('R','C'):146,('P','C'):138,('P','B'):101,('F','B'):211}
gn
{('A', 'S'): 140, ('A', 'Z'): 75, ('A', 'T'): 118, ('Z', 'O'): 71, ('S', '0'): 151, ('S', 'R'): 80, ('S', 'F'): 99, ('F', 'B'): 211, ('R', 'P'): 97, ('R', 'C'): 146, ('P', 'C'): 138, ('P', 'B'): 101}
gn('A','Z')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       gn('A','Z')
>   TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Use `gn[('A',  'Z')]` with the square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use square brackets to access the dictionary elements. I.e., access your sample dictionary as:

```
gn[('A', 'Z')]
```